# How do I get progress output from Aptitude?

Tags: aptitude

I'm upgrading some packages using Aptitude, and I want to get some program-readable status updates.  I thought I could direct `dpkg --status-fd` to a file I open in advance (regular file for this experiment, but ultimately a named pipe), like this:

```bash
aptitude -o 'Dpkg::Options::=--status-fd=3' install 3>dpkg-status-log
```

But it seems that Aptitude closes my file descriptor before it runs `dpkg`:

```
dpkg: error: unable to read filedescriptor flags for <package status and progress file descriptor>: Bad file descriptor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Is there an alternative way to get some progress feedback, short of trying to parse standard output?

Comment: What's the kind of progress information you're interested in? And what's the specific reason you need to use the rather interactive aptitude frontend for something where you need to know the progress programmatically?

Comment: @Marcus, I use Aptitude because it's usually better at resolving dependency problems (and because I know it well).  I just want to update a "progress bar" to give user feedback that we're still working towards the goal (GUI application where users wouldn't want or understand the usual stdout).  If I can use a different APT frontend, then I'm open to that suggestion.

Comment: Ooh, the hint to look at plain `apt-get` reveals `APT::Status-Fd` config option.  I think I can write my own answer based on what I found.  Stand by!

Comment: You can probably coax it with this procedure.  It seems to work for me.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars#445246

Comment: @DDay - that's something different - progress bar on a terminal, not to another program.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus for a hint that actually led to my self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pointer in APT's `README.progress-reporting` file:

> If the apt options: "`APT::Status-Fd`" is set, apt will send status
> reports to that fd.

A simple experiment using `aptitude -o 'APT::Status-Fd=3' install` works where my attempt with `Dpkg::Options::` did not, and I get a series of `pmstatus` lines that are ideal for my needs (in fact, it's more suitable than dpkg's own output, as I can just use column 3 from the `pmstatus` lines as "% complete").